# Couldn't download image as plane

Tags: image

I'm watching architectural tutorial and this add-on (Image as Plane) is not working well or I might use it wrong. So I'm trying to import image as a plane and get only plane and no image on it...can't figure out what's wromg[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Images as Planes* projects an *Image Texture* on the surface of a plane. Contrary to a *Reference Image* or a *Background Image*, which are empties (virtual objects) you can't see by default the image of the *Images as Planes* if you are in *Solid* mode (second option on the top right of your *3D View*), you need to be in *Material Preview* or *Rendered Preview* to see it, or you can stay in *Solid* mode but switch to *Color > Texture* instead of *Material* in the *Viewport Shading* panel:

[image]